# std::function crashes when used in array on stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

In MS Visual C++ 2010 SP1 this code crashes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>

int a = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    // this way it works:
    //std::vector<std::function<void ()>> s;
    //s.push_back([]() { a = 1; });
    //s.push_back([]() { a = 2; int b = a; });

    std::function<void ()> s[] = { 
        []() { a = 1; },
        []() {
            a = 2;

            // Problem occurs only if the following line is included. When commented out no problem occurs.
            int b = a;
        }
    };

    int counter = 0;
    for (auto it = std::begin(s); it != std::end(s); ++it) {
        ++counter;
        (*it)();
        std::wcout << counter << L":" << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the second array element is constructed it corrupts the first array element.

Is this an error in the compiler or have I done something that is not supported in the C++ 11 standard?

**EDIT**

This code works in gcc-4.5.1:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>

int a = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // this way it works:
    //std::vector<std::function<void ()>> s;
    //s.push_back([]() { a = 1; });
    //s.push_back([]() { a = 2; int b = a; });

    std::function<void ()> s[] = { 
        []() { a = 1; },
        []() {
            a = 2;

            // Problem occurs only if the following line is included. 
            //When commented out no problem occurs.
            int b = a;
        }
    };

    int counter = 0;
    ++counter;
    s[0]();
    std::wcout << counter << L":" << a << std::endl;
    ++counter;
    s[1]();
    std::wcout << counter << L":" << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but FWIW, works on GCC 4.6 once you've removed the MSVC specifics.

Comment: Thank you for testing with GCC 4.6. This gives some evidence for a bug in the MS compiler.

Comment: The pointers to the lambda functions are messed up in fact, I minimized the problem into that code:

    #include <functional>
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
     std::function<void ()> s[] = {
      []() {std::cout << "f0" << std::endl;},
      []() {int a=1; std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;}
     } ;
     s[0](); // output f1 instead of f0
     s[1](); // This one fail, the pointer to the function is probably messed up
    
        return 0;   }

When you call s[0], it ouput "f1"
And s[1] actually fails.

Comment: This is a bug.  The program compiles and runs without error using the Visual C++ 11 Beta.  (This will likely be the response to your [Connect Bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/734591/std-function-crashes-when-used-in-array-on-stack).)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I would accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler bug.  There's nothing wrong with your code.

Your program compiles and runs without error using the Visual C++ 11 Beta, so the bug appears to have been fixed for the forthcoming release of the compiler.

Comment: Lets hope they fix it for VC 2010 too. We cannot use C++ 11 because compiled programs do not run on Windows XP.

Comment: @frast:  I wouldn't hold your breath.  It's superlatively unlikely that this would warrant a patch for VC10, especially since there is a straightforward workaround (e.g., use `std::vector`, as you do in your second example, or initialize the array elements individually instead of using aggregate initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the capture bit?  If you want to modify a, don't you need [&a] in the beginning of your first lambda?

```
[&a]() { a = 1; },
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B

Comment: `a` should not need to be captured:  it is a global variable.

Comment: If a would be not accessible then it should be a compile-time error and not a run-time error.